# How to disable TouchSwipe plugin in cargocollective?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a page on cargocollective where I want to remove the slide functionality for changeing page since it is just annoying. I have no control over the initializing of the plugin and I would like to cancel its use after it has been initialized. Any ideas on how to do this?

The plugin is enabeld on my body element. like this.

```
$("body").touchwipe({
    wipeLeft            : function() { showNextIMG("nav") },
    wipeRight           : function() { showPrevIMG("nav") },
    min_move_x          : 20,
    min_move_y          : 20,
    preventDefaultEvents: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code apparently works!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function projectNavigation() {

    // Loading indicator
    $(".project_navigation").append($("#nav_loadspin"));

    /*
     * Keyboard navigation
     */

    shortcut.add("Up",function() { 
        $(document).trigger("closeProject");
        closeFullScreen();
        keyboard_nav        = true;
    },{ 
        'type'              : 'keydown', 
        'disable_in_input'  : true, 
        'keycode'           : 38 
    });  

    shortcut.add("Left",function() { 
        showPrevIMG("nav");
        keyboard_nav        = true;
    },{ 
        'type'              : 'keydown', 
        'disable_in_input'  : true, 'keycode':37 
    });

    shortcut.add("Right",function() { 
        showNextIMG("nav");
        keyboard_nav        = true;
    },{ 
        'type'              : 'keydown', 
        'disable_in_input'  : true, 
        'keycode'           : 39 
    });

}
</script>
```